# Utilize Space Better in iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder, autolayout

I could use some advice for how to better utilize space on the larger screen iPhones.  Here are two screenshots.  One before an app is optimized for 6 Plus, and one after. As you can see from below, once it is optimized, the buttons and image are same size and there is a lot of simple dead space.  I use `autoLayout` and have the buttons and images pinned to top and sides, or centered horizontally.  How could I go about this better?  If I make the buttons bigger, on smaller devices, they go off screen.  I'm really at a loss for formatting this one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Put (hidden) views on either side of each button and use auto layout to space things about evenly. Take a look at the section Spacing and Wrapping of [Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW7)

Comment: @MarcusAdams I see how I could space things out evenly, but wouldn't it then still be same amount of "dead space" just even on all sides?  I guess what I'm looking more for is a way to keep buttons this size on smaller devices, but larger on other devices, while still staying evenly spaced.

Comment: You need to unpin the widths of the buttons, pin them to be equal widths, and let auto layout resize the buttons for you.